# Как структурировать файл inventory

Tags: ansible

У меня ест такой файл `hosts`, со следующим содержимым:

```
 192.168.77.101 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=1 kafkaBrokerId=1
 192.168.77.102 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=2 kafkaBrokerId=2
 192.168.77.103 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant zookeeperId=3 kafkaBrokerId=3
```

Мне не нравится, что все переменные для одного сервера необходимо указывать в одну строку. Есть ли способ сделать это более симпатичным? В документации нашел только описание списка переменных для группы серверов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакой необходимости указывать все переменные в inventory файле. Собственно по лучшим практикам в inventory вообще переменных нет, только имена групп и хостов.

Ansible предполагает использовать [дерево директорий](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout):

```
production                # inventory file for production servers
staging                   # inventory file for staging environment

group_vars/
   group1.yml             # here we assign variables to particular groups
   group2.yml
host_vars/
   hostname1.yml          # here we assign variables to particular systems
   hostname2.yml

library/                  # if any custom modules, put them here (optional)
module_utils/             # if any custom module_utils to support modules, put them here (optional)
filter_plugins/           # if any custom filter plugins, put them here (optional)

site.yml                  # master playbook
webservers.yml            # playbook for webserver tier
dbservers.yml             # playbook for dbserver tier

roles/
    common/               # this hierarchy represents a "role"
        tasks/            #
            main.yml      #  <-- tasks file can include smaller files if warranted
        handlers/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- handlers file
        templates/        #  <-- files for use with the template resource
            ntp.conf.j2   #  <------- templates end in .j2
        files/            #
            bar.txt       #  <-- files for use with the copy resource
            foo.sh        #  <-- script files for use with the script resource
        vars/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- variables associated with this role
        defaults/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- default lower priority variables for this role
        meta/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- role dependencies
        library/          # roles can also include custom modules
        module_utils/     # roles can also include custom module_utils
        lookup_plugins/   # or other types of plugins, like lookup in this case

    webtier/              # same kind of structure as "common" was above, done for the webtier role
    monitoring/           # ""
    fooapp/               # ""
```

В group_vars кладутся файлы с именем `имя группы.yml` в формате yml, в host_vars - файлы с именем hostname. Имена групп и хостов те которые указаны в inventory. В этих файлах вы можете определить или переопределить переменные для группы или хоста.

Переменные могут объявляться много где, [порядок приоритета переменных определён в документации](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Так, вы можете сделать файл `group_vars/vagrant.yml`

```
---
ansible_user: vagrant
ansible_ssh_pass: vagrant
```

Затем файлы `host_vars/192.168.77.101.yml` с содержимым:

```
---
zookeeperId: 1
kafkaBrokerId: 1
```

И аналогично два других хоста.

После этого вы можете оставить в inventory только

```
[vagrant]
192.168.77.101
192.168.77.102
192.168.77.103
```

После чего можно было бы улучшить читаемость - как-то назвать этот хосты, а в переменных хостов указать `ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.77.101` для подключения.

---

Собственно две переменные явно выглядят как перечисления. Возможно вам подойдёт отдать эту заботу так же [самому ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50445356/10983392)? Объедините хосты в группу и возьмите вместо переменной позицию этого хоста в списке группы:

```
 {{groups['zookeeper'].index(inventory_hostname)}}
```

Comment: Я в inventory обычно пишу dns имена хостов. Но писать можно что угодно в качестве имён, inventory_hostname потому и отдельная переменная что зависит только от именования хоста в inventory файле